# Upgrade to Typeorm 0.3.7 Error:"Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'FindOptionsOrder<Moment>'." How can we order by moment.Moment type?

Tags: typescript, momentjs, entity, typeorm

Upgrading typeorm from version 0.2.45 to 0.3.7

```
    const userTotalEvent = await EventRepository.find({
        where: {
            user: { id: user.id },
            type,
            invitationId
        },
        order: {
            createdAt: 'DESC'
        }
    });
```

this piece of code is having this error at the `createdAt` (before upgrading typeorm it was working fine.)

Error: `**Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'FindOptionsOrder<Moment>'.**`

My Entities looks like this:

```
@Entity('event')
export default class Event extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  public id!: number;

  @ManyToOne(() => User, (user: User) => user.event)
  public user!: User;

  @Column({ type: 'int' })
  public verificationAttempts!: number;
}
```

the type or `createdAt` in the BaseEntity is `moment.Moment`:

```
export default class BaseEntity {
  @Column({ type: 'datetime', transformer: datetimeSerializer() })
  @Transform(momentToString())
  public readonly createdAt: moment.Moment;

  @Column({ type: 'datetime', transformer: datetimeSerializer() })
  @Transform(momentToString())
  public updatedAt: moment.Moment;

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.createdAt = moment();
    this.updatedAt = moment();
  }
}
```

Any one know how to solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

We've run into a similar issue. For now we've modified our `Moment` columns that used to use a custom transformer to instead be `Date` columns with getters and setters that give us the `Moment` we want to use throughout or codebase. As an example, one column used to look like:

```
  @CreateDateColumn(DATETIME)
  created_at: Moment;
```

And now, we have it as:

```
  @CreateDateColumn({ ...DATETIME, name: 'created_at' })
  _created_at: Date;

  get created_at(): Moment {
    return moment.utc(this._created_at);
  }

  set created_at(value: Moment) {
    this._created_at = value.toDate();
  }
```

It's not the cleanest solution, but it seems to be getting the job done.